# google chrome и качество изображений при сохранении pdf

Tags: css, google-chrome

**Проблема такая, гугл хром при использовании css свойств "filter" и сохранении страницы как pdf режет качество картинки до минимального. Можно ли как-то выставить качество изображений?**

Тут описывалась такая же проблема, но без решения
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570931/google-chrome-printing-images-in-low-resolution

Примеры:

Обычная страница 
[image]

К изображениям применил

```
filter: brightness(110%) saturate(160%) sepia(30%) hue-rotate(350deg) !important;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не вижу снижения качества картинок, тем более до минимума (минимальное качество выглядит [примерно так](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_001.jpg)). Вижу применение указанных фильтров.

Comment: Пожалуйста, кликните по картинкам и посмотрите на качество. Вторая картинка - это уже мыло. Например, в правом верхнем углу есть текст, на верхней картинке отчётливо видно 960 - на второй уже нет.

Comment: Если полный размер смотреть, то действительно заметна пикселизация (а не мыло!).

Comment: Но сути это не меняет. Я использую GoogleChrome/puppeteer для конвертации html в pdf. Работает отлично, также как из браузера "печать - сохранить как pdf". Но вот с фильтрами беда, а они крайне нужны. Причём при сохранении скриншота через puppeteer такой проблемы нет, изображения выглядят 1 в 1 как в html.